# Win32:OLE unable to return a list of string

Tags: perl, com

I created a Win32:OLE object in perl:

```
$myObject = Win32::OLE->new("myObject");
```

One of the APIs in my object returns a list of another object:

```
public Ilist<obj2> GetMyList()
```

It also displays the object content on cmd window and log them on disk as a txt file using the list. All the display and logging were carried out well in perl code using:

```
my $myObjList = $myObject->GetMyList();
```

but $myObjList returns undef. I tried to return a list of string and the perl variable that should be the list of strings also returned undef. Anyone seeing the same thing before?

Comment: I don't know anything about your API, but your first line has multiple syntax errors: parts of a namespace are separated by double colons `::`, method parameters are given in parens, not curlies.

Comment: Not the issue. The COM object was created successfully and running other methods fine. If a method returns string, int etc, no problem. Returning undef for lists with obj or string...

Comment: What does your IDL look like?  Or are you using C#?